# How do I have devise / omniauth redirect to the page from which I signed in from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I have the authentication through omniauth and that link is available on every page through layout/application.html.haml.

However, when they complete the omniauth authentication, they all go to root.

How can I set it up so they redirect to the actual page from which they clicked on the authentication link (which takes them to the oauth provider).

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

You can use `request.env['omniauth.origin']`.

See https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Saving-User-Location

Comment: Didn't work for me, but it would probably work had I used the sign in/up forms and actions that come with omniauth. What I got was that I was redirected back to the signin page.

Answer (score 4):

I see two options here:

1) Set a session variable on every page you could possibly sign in through like that:

```
session[:return_to] = request.fullpath
```

and redirect back to it after signing in:

```
redirect_to session[:return_to]
```

or

2) try

```
redirect_to :back
```

This depends on how you link your controller actions (haven't worked with omniauth, so I have no experience in that respect)

Comment: You should call `redirect_to session.delete(:return_to)` to clear return path.