# devise_token_auth omniauth JSON response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, devise

I have a Rails 5 site which consists of 2 parts:

1. Admin area
2. API-only client area

I'm using Devise for both parts and https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth gem for the API frontend.

The problem is about using the omniauth authentication. When I omniauth authenticate into the admin area - everything is ok - I get back some successful HTML-response.

But the problem is that I'm getting the same HTML-response in the API-area - but I need some JSON-response - not HTML one.

Here is my code:

**config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

    devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'users/sessions', :omniauth_callbacks => 'users/omniauth_callbacks' }

    namespace :api do   

        mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth', controllers: { sessions: 'api/users/sessions', :omniauth_callbacks => 'api/users/omniauth_callbacks' }    

    end
end
```

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  # Include default devise modules.
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
          :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
          :omniauthable,
          :omniauth_providers => [:facebook, :vkontakte]

  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User

  devise :omniauthable

  def self.from_omniauth_vkontakte(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.email = auth.extra.raw_info.first_name.to_s + "." + auth.extra.raw_info.last_name.to_s + '@vk.com'      
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    end
  end

end
```

**app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb**

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

  def vkontakte
    @user = User.from_omniauth_vkontakte(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Vkontakte") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.vkontakte_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end    
  end

end
```

**config/initializers/devise.rb**

```
Devise.setup do |config|

  config.omniauth :facebook, ENV["FACEBOOK_APP_ID"], ENV["FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET"], provider_ignores_state: true

  config.omniauth :vkontakte, ENV["VKONTAKTE_APP_ID"], ENV["VKONTAKTE_APP_SECRET"]

end
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-vkontakte'
```

**Gemfile.lock**

```
devise (4.3.0)
devise_token_auth (0.1.42)
```

Here's my log:

```
Started GET "/api/auth/vkontakte" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-20 17:34:23
+0300 
Started GET "/omniauth/vkontakte?namespace_name=api&resource_class=User" for
127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-20 17:34:23 +0300 
I, [2017-06-20T17:34:23.237270 #15747]  INFO -- omniauth: (vkontakte) Request phase initiated. 
Started GET "/omniauth/vkontakte/callback?code=0b8446c5fe6873bb12&state=52254649eb899e3b743779a1a4afc0304f249a6dd90b4415" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-20 17:34:23 +0300 
I, [2017-06-20T17:34:23.672200 #15747]  INFO -- omniauth: (vkontakte) Callback phase initiated. Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#vkontakte as */*   Parameters: {"code"=>"0b8446c5fe6873bb12", "state"=>"52254649eb899e3b743779a1a4afc0304f249a6dd90b4415"}
```

I guess that the problem is about a so-called "callback" url. I don't understand where it is set. It is obvious from the log that at the end of the auth process the `GET "/omniauth/vkontakte/callback..."` query is called. And probably it is called always - no matter if I initiated the oath sequence from admin or api client area.

I use Chrome Postman to make the API query `http://localhost:3000/api/auth/vkontakte` - and I get the **HTML**-response back ("successful login etc.") - but I need surely some **JSON**-response.

Is there a way to dynamically change the callback path depending on some precondition?
Is the callback query somewhat different depending on from where the oath procedure was initiated?

**EDIT1:**

This is not a single problem here unfortunately. Looks like the oauth is simply not implemented in the https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth gem. So, even if I succeed to switch the oauth login procedure to the JSON way - how do I login the user the devise_token_auth-way - generating 3 tokens etc...? The **app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb** needs to be totally reimlemented.

Answer (score 0):

You can render json from your `OmniauthCallbacksController` based on some extra parameter provided when your request a connection from the API for example. 
These extra parameters will be availables in this hash `request.env["omniauth.params"]`.

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

  def vkontakte
    @user = User.from_omniauth_vkontakte(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Vkontakte") if is_navigational_format?

      if request.env["omniauth.params"]["apiRequest"]
        render status: 200, json: { message: "Login success" }
      else
        redirect_to after_sign_in_path_for(@user)
      end
    else
      session["devise.vkontakte_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

end
```

You can this extra parameters by calling the auth helper with additional parameters, they will be passed to your OmniauthController : `user_vkontakte_omniauth_authorize_path(api_request: true)` (Or whatever your route helper is)

Comment: I tried to `GET http://localhost:3000/api/auth/vkontakte?api=true`, but no luck. The remote server does not call my callback with this new parameter.

Comment: I make a small mistake, the additional parameters will be available here `request.env["omniauth.params"]["api_request"]`, I have updated my answer

Comment: Yes, this one does work. Thanks! And I also found a similar solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396863/how-do-i-have-devise-omniauth-redirect-to-the-page-from-which-i-signed-in-from . I mean `GET http://localhost:3000/api/auth/vkontakte?api=true` causes `request.env["omniauth.params"]["api"]` to be `true`.

Comment: I have found an ever better option: I call `GET http://localhost:3000/api/auth/vkontakte` and the callback checks: `request.env["omniauth.params"]["namespace_name"] == "api"`. And when I oauth into the admin area, this value is `nil`. The benefit of this approach is that no params to the initial query are needed.

Comment: `namespace_name` is a default param with omniauth ?

Comment: I don't know. Probably not. I guess that this param is filled only because my routes. See **config/routes.rb** above: my Devise API-only area is inside `api` namespace and the Devise admin area is not inside any namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up implementing my own oauth callback procedure - instead of using one from the `devise_token_auth` gem.

The `devise_token_auth` gem does contain the oauth authentication - but it appears to be not working properly.

Here are my code changes:

**config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

    devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'users/sessions', :omniauth_callbacks => 'users/omniauth_callbacks' }

    namespace :api do   

        mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth', controllers: { sessions: 'api/users/sessions'}   

    end
end
```

**app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb**

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken

  def vkontakte
    @user = User.from_omniauth_vkontakte(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    namespace_name = request.env["omniauth.params"]["namespace_name"]

    if @user.persisted?

      if namespace_name && namespace_name == "api"

        @client_id = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(nil, false)
        @token     = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(nil, false)

        @user.tokens[@client_id] = {
          token: BCrypt::Password.create(@token),
          expiry: (Time.now + DeviseTokenAuth.token_lifespan).to_i
        }
        @user.save

        @resource = @user # trade-off for "update_auth_header" defined in "DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken"

        sign_in(:user, @user, store: false, bypass: false)        

        render json: @user

      else

        sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
        set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Vkontakte") if is_navigational_format?

      end

    else
      session["devise.vkontakte_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end    
  end

end
```

The inclusion of `include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken` provides 5 auth headers in response:

```
access-token →BeX35KJfYVheKifFdwMPag
client →96a_7jXewCThas3mpe-NhA
expiry →1499340863
token-type →Bearer
uid →376449571
```

But the response still lacks these headers (available at a common sign-in):

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials →true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods →GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin →chrome-extension://aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo
Access-Control-Max-Age →1728000
```

I don't know whether they are important and if yes - how to provide them.

PS The same identical approach works with Facebook too.